# Como usar o Quartz Scheduler com o Demoiselle?

Tags: java, demoiselle

Criei um job usando o Quartz Scheduler dentro de uma aplicação web Java que usa o framework Demoiselle com JSF e Tomcat 7.

O job deve chamar um método de um Business Controller (BC), que chama um DAO para alterar o banco de dados. No entanto, não consegui injetar o BC no job; mesmo passando o BC para o job de outra forma, ao chamar o BC a partir do do job, a aplicação lança uma `ContextNotActiveException`.

Como fazer para chamar um método de um BC a partir de um job Quartz?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nos casos mais comuns, o código do BC é chamado a partir de um managed bean (MB) cuja execução foi originada por uma requisição HTTP feita pelo navegador web. Nesses casos, existe um RequestContext ativo que permite que você use o `@Inject`.

O problema é que o job roda em uma thread separada, que não tem acesso a um contexto. Para resolver isso, você deve passar o BC para o job e, dentro do job, criar um contexto de request.

A classe que cria o job deve injetar o BC e um RequestContext; ao criar o job, esses objetos devem ser passados para o job através de um JobDataMap:

```java
@BusinessController
public class Agendador {
  @Inject
  private MinhaClasseBC meuObjetoBC;
  @Inject
  private BoundRequestContext requestContext;

  public void agendaJob() throws SchedulerException {
    JobDataMap jobData = new JobDataMap();
    jobData.put("requestContext", requestContext);
    jobData.put("bc", meuObjetoBC);

    JobDetail job = newJob(ClasseDoJob.class)
        .withIdentity("id", "grupo")
        .setJobData(jobData)
        .build();

    // aqui vem o código da trigger e do agendamento
  }
}
```

A classe do job, então, pega esses objetos e cria o contexto antes de chamar o BC (e destrói após a chamada):

```java
public class ClasseDoJob implements Job {
  @Override
  public void execute(JobExecutionContext jobContext) throws JobExecutionException {
    JobDataMap jobData = jobContext.getJobDetail().getJobDataMap();
    BoundRequestContext ctx = (BoundRequestContext)jobData.get("requestContext");
    MinhaClasseBC bc = (MinhaClasseBC)jobData.get("bc");

    ctx.associate(new HashMap<String, Object>());
    ctx.activate();

    bc.metodoQueFazAlgumaCoisa();

    ctx.invalidate();
    ctx.deactivate();
  }
}
```

Comment: Curiosamente, esse código só compila no JDK da Oracle. No OpenJDK, ele não consegue encontrar o pacote `org.jboss.weld.context.bound`, onde fica a classe `BoundRequestContext`.

Comment: Retificando: o código compila tanto no OpenJDK quanto no JDK da Oracle. O problema que enfrentei foi uma confusão com as dependências.

Comment: Tou penando aqui como pegar um MB dentro desse método execute no antigo Primefaces 6 (não tem como mudar a versão) e Java 8. Alguém teria alguma dica de como pegar esse Managed Bean?

Answer (score 1):

Este é um "problema" geral do CDI. Para que o Inject, Interceptor, Scopes, etc funcionem é necessário um ambiente CDI rodando. Estes ambientes estão disponíveis nos containers Java EE 6+ ou em implementações SE como é o caso do Weld SE, por exemplo.

Neste seu caso (aplicação EE, suponho) sugiro uma abordagem bem diferente da que você está tentando. Utilize o seu agendador de tarefas (Quartz, cron, IFTTT, ou o que for) para acionar chamadas HTTP para sua aplicação.

Na aplicação você pode implementar a "porta de acesso" com Servlet ou REST. Na sua aplicação cliente (o agendador de tarefas) consumiria um serviço HTTP da aplicação onde todo o contexto CDI estaria pronto e funcional.

Veja que esta é a solução adotada pelos principais PaaS e IaaS (Cloud Computing) a exemplo do Google AppEngine e Redhat Openshift.

Para aplicações SE, elas já se resolvem sozinhas sem a necessidade de serviços ou agendadores externos. Seu caso tem muito mais cara de aplicações EE e este foi o foco da resposta.

Comment: Sim, meu caso é EE. Entendo que existem trade-offs: é preciso ter a URL da aplicação, e a URL pode variar de acordo com o ambiente de implantação (testes, produção etc.); um visitante mal-intencionado que descobrir a URL da "porta de acesso" pode executar a tarefa com frequência maior do que a desejada. Por causa disso vou manter minha resposta, mas se precisar fazer algo semelhante no futuro vou considerar a sua solução.